# installing nvidia driver on eks nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, gpu, devops, nvidia, amazon-eks

I have a EKS cluster that has two node pools. One CPU general compute, the other one has GPU support (g4dn). I want to install nvidia driver on to the GPU node group. The best I can do right now is to manually ssh onto each node and install. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you manage your EKS cluster.

One of recommended tools is [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/introduction/), which brings out of box support for [GPU node group](https://eksctl.io/usage/gpu-support/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move away from manually installing the GPU driver on your node then you will have to use the tool called (packer)[https://www.packer.io] that will help you bake a custom EKS ami.

In your packer configuration, you will have to add the steps to install the GPU Driver.

You can then use that custom ami in your EKS Cluster, which will have the driver pre-installed for you.

AWS has few resources for this.See below link

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-custom-linux-ami/